# Take data within a month, if not, then in the previous one

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my application, I use this select to get data in a month:

```
select e.id, e.date, e.local_currency_id, e.rate, e.downloaddate
from exchange_rates e
join (select local_currency_id, max(date) as max_date
from exchange_rates group by local_currency_id, date_trunc('month', date)) as m_date on e.date = m_date.max_date
where e.date >=:currentDate and e.local_currency_id = :localCurrencyId
order by date_trunc('month', e.downloaddate) desc limit 1
```

The question is that I want to get the data in the month (local_currency), sorting from the end of the month, in reverse order, and if there is no data in this month, then I need to take the data in the previous one.

Now, according to my select, I get data that is greater than my date, but I need to get the data as I described above

Comment: I would probably agree with the postes answer, but it's difficult so say. Please add some sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not totally following your logic by how about use row_number() to do a ranking.
partition by the currency id and order by the date descending.   then just pick  the ranking of 1. (the most current)

```
with t as (select e.*,
row_number() over (partition by e.local_currency_id order by date_trunc('month', e.downloaddate) desc) as rn
from exchange_rates e
where e.local_currency_id = :localCurrencyId)
select id, date, local_currency_id, rate, downloaddate
from t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: The question is that I want to get the data in the month (local_currency), sorting from the end of the month, in reverse order, and if there is no data in this month, then I need to take the data in the previous one.

Comment: I have revised my question.
In your select, I get data not for a month, but for the entire period of time. Your select is not month oriented. It focuses on all the data that is in the database.

Comment: maybe just change the order by in the partition? I updated the answer